# Zabbix user-defined parameters with PSK encryption

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to configure a user defined parameter on a Windows host.  All my hosts are configured with PSK encryption and Zabbix server is able to get data without any issues.
However I cannot figure out how to use the zabbix_get manually with PSK encryption enabled.

zabbix_get -s x.x.x.x -p 10050 -k "internet.connection.check" --tls-connect=psk --tls-psk-identity="name" --tls-psk-file=cannot find any psk file on zabbix server

The problem is I cannot locate any PSK file on the zabbix server. Can I pass the PSK somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The serverside PSK is configured in the GUI and stored in the database.
The Zabbix agent stores the PSK in a file.

I see 3 options:

1. Manually create a psk-file.
   Remember that a change of the key must be done in the GUI, at the agent and in your special file.
2. Make a script that reads the key from the database.
   Remember that direct access to the database of an application is most times forbidden and  can cause compatibility issues after updating the application. Read-only access should be possible.
3. Use the same keys for all your agents;
   When you install a Zabbix Agent on the Zabbix Server (allowing you to monitor the server), you do have a file on a normal place.

I wouldn't try to use an API or some smart script during Discovery, this will make the solution hard to maintain. I withdraw my last remark, when you have thousands of servers to monitor and a team working with Zabbix.